# Data Access Design Pattern

Tags: c#, json, mvvm, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm currently building a Windows 8 Store app that requires me to make several web service calls. The calls return a json string that I'm deserializing into objects. I'm using the MVVM design pattern with Caliburn.Micro for WinRT.

Initially, in order to get the data from the web service calls to each of my View Models, I created a class, DataStore, that declared a static instance of itself. That class had properties that corresponded to all my models. When a web service call needed to be made I called a static class method in "APIData" that read in a dictionary of parameters, serialized those parameters into JSON, made the API call and returned the JSON result to the DataStore class. At which point the JSON was deserialized and used to update the DataStore properties. In each of my ViewModels I referenced whichever DataStore property was needed for the datacontext of that VM.

This resulted in repeated code and a very messy DataStore class.

My question is, what would be a good design pattern to use where json returned from webservice calls must be used to populate models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your initial attempt has broken the '[single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)' and that has led to the very messy DataStore class.

My implementation of viewmodel data operations is to hold a collection of 'ViewModelPopulator' classes. Each service populated viewmodel holds a reference to a viewmodelpopulator who's responsibility it is to hydrate the viewmodels properties.

To promote code reuse it is possible that a single viewmodel may be populated by different populators (for example, a '`CarCollectionViewModel`' being populated by either a '`HondaCollectionViewModelPopulator`' or a '`KiaCollectionViewModelPopulator`') therefore the reference is actually to an `IViewModelPopulator<T>` where T is the viewmodel to populate.

This results in loose coupling between the viewmodels and the data access layer. In your example I would place the Json deserialisation (probably through some helper methods) in the viewmodelpopulator classes.

Additionally, this allows you to declaratively inject populators into a viewmodel from the UI layer at design time (as per the example below), or to assign them in the codebehind at runtime.

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <VM:SearchPageViewModel>
        <VM:SearchPageViewModel.ViewModelPopulator>
            <VMP:SearchPageViewModelPopulator />
        </VM:SearchPageViewModel.ViewModelPopulator>
    </VM:SearchPageViewModel>
</Page.DataContext>
```